# Related to push notifications in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have seen all the links related to Push notifications in Google. And read
[Programming Apple Push Notification Services](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services) on MobiForge. From this I have created the certificates and created the app and got the Device token by running the application. But after that how can i get the notification (either in local or remote way). If any one know please give me a clear idea.

Comment: There are two services that are needed to perform push notifications for iOS.  One is from Apple that gives you the token.  The other is your own push notification server.  You need to either create that server yourself and host it or use a their party like Urban AirShip. If you are familiar with Rails, I think there is even a gem available to set up that service.  Once you have that server set up then your app needs to contact that server, and pass it the token. Once you device is registered on both your server and Apples, you can use your server to push to the registered device.

Comment: Hi carbonbasednerd, Thanks for ur response. I got the Device token but i didn't get any notification upto now. Am i need to do anything.

Comment: What are you using for your push notification server?  Urban Airship?  something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the above link fully; you would be able to test the notification. More to this there are few players who are giving paid services to do push notifications and give you wizard to prepare your notification. e.g Urban AirShip.

More to this please follow the following links.

1. [iOs Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080279/ios-push-notifications)
2. [Push Notifications Certificates Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421800/push-notifications-certificates-question)
3. [Apple PNS (push notification services) sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052645/apple-pns-push-notification-services-sample-code)

Comment: Hi Jigar AKA Jack ,Thanks for ur response. I got the Device token but i didn't get any notification upto now. Am i need to do anything.